# Data not rendered using sj:select tag in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am new in Struts 2 and want to add some jQuery to my Struts application but I am having some issue, I have done a lot but find nothing.

I want to implement Struts jQuery select tag but having some problems.  here is my code

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <package extends="struts-default,json-default" name="default" namespace="/">           
            <action class="org.actions.JsonS" name="jsondata" >
                <result type="json" />
            </action>         
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`welcome.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsondata.action" />
    <sj:select href="%{remoteurl}" id="mylist" list="nolist" name="mylist" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**`JsonS.java`:**

```
package org.actions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class JsonS {
         private List<String> nolist;
         
         public String execute() {
             nolist = new ArrayList<String>();
             nolist.add("one");
             return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
         }
         
         public String getJSON() {
             return execute();
         }

        public List<String> getNolist() {
            return nolist;
        }
}
```

when I manually checking JSON response everything working fine. I m getting this response.

```
{"JSON":"success","nolist":["one"]}
```

but when I want to use it with Struts jQuery select it's not working nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url and header from

```
<head>
</head>  

<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsondata.action" />
```

to

```
<head>
  <sj:head/>
</head>  

<s:url var="remoteurl" namespace="/" action="jsondata" />
```

For this and further references, to be working ensure you have [struts2-jquery plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=119537#content/view/119537) included in the war build.

Comment: @user2320220 Are you sure?

Comment: Hey Roman, I have one question, there is normal jquery library, with jquery i can do lot of things. why should i use struts 2 jquery lib, i m little confuse. do you have any idea

Comment: @user2320220 jquery is a pure javascript, no taglib.

Comment: @user2320220 If you followed the link to the project page there's description on the top, the plugin is made of jquery that is embedded in the jar and you could combine the power of struts tags with jquery together. You could do everything with jquery on the client but not on the server without ajaxing the server for the data.

Comment: @user2320220: You don't need to use struts2-jquery-plugin. It just simplifies/makes more difficult, javascript stuff.